# On the assignment of axial and equatorial to substiuents of polyhexacyclics

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

Must the assignment of axial and equatorial substituents of polyhexacyclics always be with respect to each six-membered ring or is there a shorthand?

For example, how would X, Y, and Z be assigned axial/equatorial in the following substituted adamantane?

[image: trisubstituted adamantane]

Comment: It depends upon which ring is the reference. Equatorial to ring "A" can be axial to "B".

Comment: What would Z be relative to the ring that has both X and Y as substiuents (the one at the bottom)?

Comment: The perspective of Z is not drawn well but it appears to be axial to the ring bearing X in which case both X and Z are axial to their common ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure you have drawn where X = Y = Z = H is known as [adamantane](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/adamantanes.html), C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>16</sub>. It has 3 [degrees of unsaturation](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/unsaturation/unsat.html) but visually appears to have 4 rings. Once 3 rings have been defined (rings A, B and C), then all C-C bonds have been accounted for. Put another way, you only need to erase three C-C bonds and add hydrogen to obtain a saturated, acyclic hydrocarbon, C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>22</sub>.
In structure **1** ring A is highlighted in red with X and Y equatorial to ring A. In structure **2** substituents X and Z are both axial to ring B. Structure **3** has the configuration of the Z substituent changed to equatorial relative to ring B. Ring C bears the same relationship to ring A as ring B does to ring A. Therefore in structure **4**, substituent Y is axial to ring C. Now locate ring "D" and define equatorial/axial relationships of the Z substituent to ring "D" in structures **1** - **4**.

[image]

Comment: I used the URL of the image from your first version.